# Display content of cell array corresponding to another cell array with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a dataset stored in SUBJ{s}.,and then fields SUBJ.WORDS{w} and SUBJ.RECALL{r}. I tried to create a loop that finds when SUBJ.RECALL corresponds to 1 (1=word remembered, 0 not remembered). After  that I want to have displayed the words that correspond to the positions where SUBJ.RECALL is 1. Say

```
 SUBJ{1}.WORDS{1}={‘Apple’, ‘Melon’, ‘Cheese’ ,’Pancakes’,Tomatoes’}% words presented.
`SUBJ{1}.RECALL{1}=[1 0 0 1 1]% 1=word recalled 0=word non recalled.
```

What I want is to display the words that have been recalled, meaning the words that correspond to 1 in SUBJ.RECALL.
I have done this:

```
for s=1:length(SUBJ)
    for w=1:length(SUBJ.WORDS)
        for r=1:length(SUBJ.RECALL)
            if SUBJ{s}.RECALL{r}==1
                disp(SUBJ{s}.WORDS{(SUBJ.RECALL{r}==1)})
            end
        end
    end
end
```

> Error: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

```
for s=1:length(SUBJ)
    for w=1:length(SUBJ.WORDS)
        for r=1:length(SUBJ.RECALL)
            find(SUBJ{s}.RECALL{r}==1)
            disp(SUBJ{s}.WORDS{(SUBJ.RECALL{r}==1)})
        end
    end
end
```

> Error: Attempt to reference field of non-structure

Thanks in advance for any comment!

Comment: Are you sure the errors are inside the loop and not in these calls length(SUBJ.RECALL)? Shouldn't it be length(SUBJ{1}.RECALL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not need this many for-loops, as you can process the cell element contents using `find`. I included a sample code below. This works for your sample data, but might fail with whole dataset as i don't know the structure.

```
for s=1:length(SUBJ)
    % Store in variables to make code more readable
    words = SUBJ{s}.WORDS{1};
    hits = SUBJ{s}.RECALL{1};
    if max(hits) == 1 % Only print when hits
        disp(words(find(hits)))
    end
end
```